# Package dependencies cannot be resolved error while installing r-base from Ubuntu Software center

Tags: r, ubuntu-14.04

The message says:-

> This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable.

Furthermore, there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

Details:-
The following packages have unmet dependencies:-

r-base: Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.4.3-1trusty0) but 3.4.3-1trusty0 is to be installed
        Depends: r-recommended (= 3.4.3-1trusty0) but 3.4.3-1trusty0 is to be installed

I have also tried the code:-

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:texlive-backports/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

I cannot understand how to instal R in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Try this: 
`sudo apt-get install aptitude`
`sudo aptitude install -f r-base`